# XML in Classic ASP Vbscript

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

I am back to asp with XML manupulation.
Initial file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <sport/>
</root>
```

this is my function

```
Public Function DefinitFunction( x,z)


Dim text 
Dim Root
Dim NodeList

    text = "<Definition>" ---<x> </x> <z> </z> --</Definition> " 
    text = text & "<x><![CDATA["&x&"]]> </x>"
    text = text & "<z> </z>"        
    text = text & "</Definition>"

Set Root = objDoc.documentElement 
Set NodeList = Root.getElementsByTagName("sport") 

NodeList.appendChild text 

objDoc.Save strFile

end function
'  Private strFile, objDoc are class object
```

I want to modify the all thing dynamically. So I have a function :
`DefinitFunction(x,z)` that will concatenate a string and append `<Definition> ---<x> </x> <z> </z> --</Definition>` in my file right after the Node `<sport>`
at the end this should be my result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <sport>
    <Definition>
        ---<x> </x> <z> </z> --
      </Definition> 
   </sport>
</root>
```

This is not working. Is there any better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Its not entirely clear from your code sample, but are you using the MSXML object or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot append text directly .. you need to convert it to XML node first..

```
Set newXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
newXML.async = False 
newXML.loadXML( "<root>" & text & "</root>")

NodeList.appendChild( newXML.documentElement.selectSingleNode("/Definition"))
```

Comment: Nope
Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01B6)
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'NodeList.appendChild'

Comment: do not use `Root.getElementsByTagName("sport")` to get to sport.. use `Root.selectSingleNode("sport")`. The first returns a node list (*to which you cannot append directly*) the second returns a node (*which supports the appendChild..*)

Comment: This is a plus.thanks. However it append outside of the sport node <sport> </sport>
 <Definition> ---<x> </x> <z> </z> -- </Definition>
instead of 
<sport> <Definition> ---<x> </x> <z> </z> -- </Definition> </sport>

Comment: All good. my bad
It all good 
Thanks for your help 
from the future expert in xml -asp

Comment: no problem ZAfrican .. have fun with xml ;) (*you should go back to your questions and accept answers if they were helpful .. this will make people more eager to answer your future questions..*)